# When a Summoner uses Act Together for 3 actions, do they need to do an activity worth 3 actions or can they take 3 actions individually?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, summoner, eidolon

The "[Act Together](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=758)" activity reads:

> You and your eidolon act as one. Either you or your eidolon takes an
> **action or activity using the same number of actions as Act Together**,
> and the other takes a single action. For example, if you spent 2
> actions to Act Together, you could cast burning hands (2 actions) and
> your eidolon could Strike (1 action), or your eidolon could use its
> Breath Weapon (2 actions) and you could Stride (1 action).

So, if the summoner uses act together for 3, giving themselves one action to stride, can the eidolon do stride-strike-strike? Or is it limited to a single strike or a 3 action activity?

Comment: What's the goal of what you are trying to accomplish? Or does Blckknght's answer clear up a misunderstanding?

Comment: It does answer me, I didn't know the eidolon could take actions without the act together

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Act Together* combines only two activities, one for the Summoner and one for the Eidolon. One of the activities needs to cost one action, and will become effectively free when using Act Together. The other activity can have any cost (1-3 actions) and that cost is action the cost of Act Together. Either partner (Summoner or Eidolon) can take the more costly activity.

So if you wanted your Summoner to stride and the Eidolon to stride-stride-strike, you can all of do that in a turn, but it won't all be part of *Act Together*. The *Act Together* action would only include the Summoner striding and the Eidolon doing their first stride, and it would cost one action. The Eidolon's other two actions would just be normal actions, taken after *Act Together*.

An example of a two action *Act Together* is a Dragon Eidolon using its *Breath Weapon* (which costs two actions), and the Summoner doing a strike. You'd also have one more action that either the Summoner or Eidolon could use.

An example of an *Act Together* that costs 3 actions would be when the Summoner casts a 3-action spell, like *Summon Animal*. If they use *Act Together*, their Eidolon can also perform an activity that costs one action (e.g. stride or strike). The whole *Act Together* action cost will match the cost of the spell, in this case three actions. (The summoned creature also gets two actions after it appears, as usual.)

There are a few activities that can't be used with *Act Together*, because they represent an action that both the Summoner and the Eidolon are doing together already. Those activities are marked by the *Tandem* trait.

Comment: so in this case, if you use act together for three actions, you need to be doing a three action activity

Comment: So really, the question seems to be looking at it from the wrong direction.  It shouldn't be "I'm spending actions on Act Together, now what can I do with it?".  Rather, it should be "I want to do something together with my Eidolon, so how many actions will I need to spend on Act Together?".

Comment: This answer is pretty good, but I'd like it to include a second example where Act Together is used as a 2/3-Action Activity (such as casting a Summon spell)

Comment: @Ifusaso: Sure, I can add one.